# Require.js + jQuery + BlockUI causes mismatch error, why?

Tags: requirejs, blockui, mismatch

In order for jQuery to hook onto require.js, jQuery has to be loaded *after* require.js. That works fine, but as soon as i include a jQuery plugin called BlockUI, which does some weird AMD stuff ([see bottom of BlockUI source](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.blockUI.js)), i get a mismatch error. I know BlockUI is causing this because the mismatch error spits out the entire source, and everything works if i remove BlockUI. It doesn't matter if utilize require.js or not; just including the library is enough.

See this jsfiddle:
http://goo.gl/4tYE7

Switch over to the Resources tab on the left, to verify that all scripts are loaded in the correct order. All good? Good, now open the console. POW! Blood everywhere!

I'm not sure if this is a Require.js or BlockUI bug (i'm betting BlockUI since it's a bit outdated), but is there any workaround for this? What is actually happening in the bottom of BlockUI? jQuery exposes itself as an AMD module at the bottom of the source, why does BlockUI do similar things?

I don't have much control over the loading of BlockUI because it's loaded by a Wordpress plugin (Jigoshop), so getting this to work is rather important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you using BlockUI? Are you requiring it or using it as a dependency? Taken from the RequireJS site:

> If you manually code a script tag in HTML to load a script with an
>   anonymous define() call, this error can occur.
>
> Also seen if you
>   manually code a script tag in HTML to load a script that has a few
>   named modules, but then try to load an anonymous module that ends up
>   having the same name as one of the named modules in the script loaded
>   by the manually coded script tag. Finally, if you use the loader
>   plugins or anonymous modules (modules that call define() with no
>   string ID) but do not use the RequireJS optimizer to combine files
>   together, this error can occur.
>
> The optimizer knows how to name
>   anonymous modules correctly so that they can be combined with other
>   modules in an optimized file. To avoid the error: Be sure to load all
>   scripts that call define() via the RequireJS API. Do not manually code
>   script tags in HTML to load scripts that have define() calls in them.
>   If you manually code an HTML script tag, be sure it only includes
>   named modules, and that an anonymous module that will have the same
>   name as one of the modules in that file is not loaded. If the problem
>   is the use of loader plugins or anonymous modules but the RequireJS
>   optimizer is not used for file bundling, use the RequireJS optimizer.

http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html

If you use jQuery and BlockUI as modules it will work just fine:

```
require.config({
    'paths': {
        'jquery': 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min',
        'blockUI': 'http://malsup.github.com/jquery.blockUI'    
    },
    'shim': {
        'blockUI': ['jquery']    
    }
})

require(['blockUI'], function(){
    // Don't return a value to the callback as it just augments the $.fn
    console.log($.fn.block);
    console.log($.fn.unblock);
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/Blink/ae4nr/

> What is actually happening in the bottom of BlockUI? jQuery exposes
>   itself as an AMD module at the bottom of the source, why does BlockUI
>   do similar things?

It's a known technique for supporting AMD with plugins and such. Wrapping the code in a function means that the `window.jQuery` can be passed in if no AMD is present otherwise the function can be passed to `define` and then jQuery will be passed to it once it loads. Either way, all the plugin code cares about is receiving the jQuery object to use as $.

Defining 'jquery' as a path is a requirement of using it with AMD so the plugin author can safely assume that 'jquery' will be defined:

```
define(['jquery'], setup);
```

Comment: I don't have much control over how jQuery and BlockUI are loaded. I'm using Wordpress (although not a big fan), and a plugin called Jigoshop automatically adds a BlockUI script tag to the header along with some other scripts. jQuery is also loaded automatically by Wordpress. The jsfiddle i linked is pretty much what i have going on in my header. I wish i had more control, but unfortunately i don't. In the end, i don't really care what goes on in the header, because my scripts are placed in the footer. All i need for my scripts to work is for jQuery to be loaded. That's when things get messy...

Comment: ...In order for require.js to use jQuery as a dependency i need to include require before jQuery, but if include require.js before jquery, everything else in the header (BlockUI, for example) will try to hook itself up, causing errors. If i could load require.js in the footer, and somehow depend on jQuery to load other modules, that would be great. Do you see my problem?

Comment: Can you modify the plugin? Take out the script injection and load it yourself through require? If not why are you using require at all? Sounds like the way your theme/plugins are built does not lend itself well to this patten

Comment: Nope, not really. I really don't have any control over what Wordpress plugins spit out in the header. I mean, i can manually go in and edit the plugins, but that will break updates etc. I am using require to organize my theme's js code, which is separate from what Wordpress loads. I have several modules that are specific to my theme and are loaded and managed through require, but none of my modules depend on anything in the header (except for jQuery, which is only loaded in the header because other scripts WP spits out are dependent on jQuery before they load)...

Comment: ...Prior to implementing require i had all of my theme's javascript code in one huge, incredibly messy file. I much prefer having it separated into files because it is more organized, and it also makes the code much cleaner and more readable. If an AMD is not the correct way to go, then what is?

Comment: A tricky one. Often hard to mix AMD with normal static scripts. Sounds like you should keep AMD as it's working for your other stuff. How about removing the define from the BlockUI script? If it's being loaded as a normal script regardless in the head, then you could just leave it out of your AMD setup. Not pretty by any means but restrictions are restrictions

Comment: Editing the BlockUI script is not an alternative because other libraries added by plugins will probably run into the same issue, and i can't edit all of the libraries. Something i could do is load jQuery in the header, then load Require in the footer. Since jQuery loads first it will *most likely* complete loading before the main script loads. Do you think this is a safe approach? If jQuery didn't finish loading before the main script runs, there will be a shitstorm of errors.

Comment: If you put Require in the footer and jQuery in the header then you can be sure jQuery will be there as script elements are parsed before the browser continues with the rest of the document. Not the cleanest solution but I can't think of much else :)